# Rails Error: "Could not find gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I did gem mysql2. This is how my GemFile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'mysql2' 
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

This is my configuration file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: qac_db
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the line `gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'`. Then run `bundle install`.

Comment: Then, I get an error: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- java) when I run rake db:create

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I deleted my database.yml, and recreated it, then everything started working. No idea why, permissions problem perhaps?